# Common Configuration strategy for .Net Framework and .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, configuration-files

It’s more of an architecture related question. I am working on to extend.net framework application to add .net core support as well. Now my application is using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class to read all the configurations and that class is important as some configurations related to reading dynamics modules are used at the time of bootstrapping the DI. Now I see .net core does not rely on this `ConfigurationManager` class and has its own appsettings configuration file in JSON format. This would require me to change the strategy to have a common logic supporting both framework and core.

I am seeking any advice on how the community is addressing this problem and what is the best way forward.

**App.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EndPointAssembliesPath" value="<some directory path>" />
    <add key="ModulesPath" value="<some directory path>" />
    <add key="BusinessAssembliesScanningPattern" value="*.BusinessModule.*.dll" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DataSource;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"EndPointAssembliesPath": "<some path>",
"BusinessModulesPath": "<some directory path>",
"BusinessAssembliesScanningPattern": "*.BusinessModule.*.dll",
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CompanyDatabase": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DataSource;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
}
```

Comment: You can use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and related APIs in .NET Framework, using JSON files for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [Configuration providers in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#file-configuration-provider). All the samples are intended to be used with .NET Core, but most of the NuGet packages are compatible with .NET Standard 2.0. Therefore you should be able to consume them from any .NET Framework application being compatible to .NET Standard 2.0.

Your code could look a bit like this:

```cs
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
var config = configurationBuilder.Build();
```

From that on, you can work with the unified `config` object.

Disclaimer: I didn't test it, but I'm quite confident

Comment: This wouldn't work. `app.config` has a very specific structure and won't be parsed to get the specific settings. It'd be easier to just keep everything in the json file

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can you please explain a bit more in detail what you mean? I've created a little .NET Core Console App and had no problem to parse the XML file 

Comment: Did you use a .NET Framework's app.config file with configuration settings in the correct place? Notice that the OP didn't post a correct app.config file, only some parts of it

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/mu88/NetConfigProviderSample

Comment: Nice! It seems that they added a special case for app.config then

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it: why should they add a special case when implementing XML support in general? Every valid `App.config` file is a valid XML file and therefore there should be no need for special cases

Comment: Well... taking a look at your example, the .json file isn't really the normal one. I have never used nor seen an "appSettings" property in a appsettings.json file, and I've been using ASP.NET Core since 1.0 preview 4.

Comment: @mu88, the project is failing when app.config contains other details like runtime and assemblyBinding, System.FormatException: 'XML namespaces are not supported. Line 10, position 22.'

Answer (score -1):

Check if the app is using a web.config file or a json file. An example for a connection string:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"] != null)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }
        else
        {
            var connString = AppConfigSettings.Current.AppConnection;
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
        }
    }
```